# Why is this prompting not working? MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

```
# PART 1 

    .data   # Data declaration section
sourceprompt:   .ascii  "Enter a source string: "

queryprompt:    .ascii  "Enter a query string: "

replaceprompt:  .ascii  "Enter a replace string: "

nomatch:    .ascii  "Nothing to replace "

source:         .space  256 

query:          .space  256

replace:        .space  256

    .text

main:                       # Start of code section

    li $v0, 4               # Load system call for printing into $v0
    la $a0, sourceprompt            # Load address of string into $a0
    syscall                 # call operating system to perform operation

    li $v0, 8               # Load system call for reading string into $v0
    la $a0, source              # Load byte space into source so string has a place to go
    li $a1  256             # Set the byte space for the string
    syscall

    move $t1, $a0               #move source out of a0 so it doesn't get replaced  

    li $v0, 4               # Load system call for printing into $v0
    la $a0, queryprompt         # Load address of string into $a0
    syscall                 # call operating system to perform operation

    li $v0, 8               # Load system call for reading string into $v0
    la $a0, query               # Load byte space into buffer so string has a place to go
    li $a1  256                 # Set the byte space for the string
    syscall                 # call operating system to perform operation

    move $t2, $a0               #move query into t2


    li $v0, 4               # Load system call for printing into $v0
    la $a0, replaceprompt           # Load address of string into $a0
    syscall                 # call operating system to perform operation

    li $v0, 8               # Load system call for reading string into $v0
    la $a0, replace             # Load byte space into buffer so string has a place to go
    li $a1  256                 # Set the byte space for the string
    syscall                 # call operating system to perform operation

    move $t3, $a0               #move replace into t3
```

PRINTS

> Enter a source string: Enter a query string: Enter a replace string:
>   Nothing to replace

i don't want that! i want it to prompt one by one! why is it doing htat?!!

Answer (score 1):

Those strings aren't null terminated. Use .asciiz instead.